# Can't Delete Item From Localstorage - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I've just started learning about localstorage in javascript, so I'm working on a project to practice. My program is a bookmark manager. The user can input a name and the url for there webpage, then it'll be stored and prepended to a div. If the user clicks on a trash icon, I want to find the url link that is associated with that trash icon, then remove it from localstorage.

Here's a link to the code and a demo.
[LINK](http://codepen.io/thejseffect/pen/wgrajV?editors=0010)

JS

```
// READY
$(document).ready(() => {
    // when user clicks on submit
    $(".submit").on("click", addItem);
    // when user clicks on delete
    $(".fa-trash").on("click", deleteItem);

    // show bookmarks
    showBookmarks();
})

// ADD ITEM
let addItem = (e) => {
    // get values from inputs
    let name = $(".name").val();
    let link = $(".url").val();

    // stores bookmarks
    let bookmark = {
        name: name,
        url: link
    };

    // bookmark varification
    // if theres nothing in bookmarks
    if(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks") == null) {
        // init array
        let bookmarks = [];

        // add to array
        bookmarks.push(bookmark);

        // set to local storage
        localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    } else { // if theres something in bookmarks
        // get from local storage
        let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

        // add bookmark to array
        bookmarks.push(bookmark);

        // reset back to local storage
        localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
    }
}

// SHOW BOOKMARKS
let showBookmarks = () => {
    // get from local storage
    let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

    // loop through local storage data
    for(let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
        let name = bookmarks[i].name;
        let url = bookmarks[i].url;

        // append bookmarks
        $(".show").prepend(`
            <div class="bookmark">
                <a href="${url}" target="_blank">${name}</a>
                <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        `);
    }
}

// DELETE ITEM
let deleteItem = (url) => {
    // get bookmarks from localstorage
    let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

    // loop through bookmarks
    for(let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
        if(bookmarks[i].url == url) {
            // remove from array
            bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    // reset local storage
    localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));

    showBookmarks();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Which part of your code is not working?

Comment: The `deleteItem()`

Comment: Are you trying to delete a. Newly created element??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never passing the url, but you can derive it from event object like this:

```
let deleteItem = (event) => {
    // get bookmarks from localstorage
var a = $(event.target).siblings("a");
var url = $(a).attr("href");        
let bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

// loop through bookmarks
for(let i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++) {
    if(bookmarks[i].url == url) {
        // remove from array
        console.log("removing i");
        bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

// reset local storage
localStorage.setItem("bookmarks", JSON.stringify(bookmarks));

showBookmarks();
```

}

Comment: Also, using $(document).on("click", '.fa-trash', deleteItem) worked instead of $(".fa-trash").on("click", deleteItem);

Answer (score 1):

$(".fa-trash").on("click", deleteItem);

Should be

$(document).on("click", '.fa-fresh', deleteItem);

Answer (score 1):

You are using the method for storing, not for removing. Your code should be like

```
localStorage.removeItem("bookmarks");
```

you can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage)

Answer (score 0):

Use this  localStorage.removeItem(key);

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where `localStorage.removeItem('myItem');` was not truly deleting the item. 
I found that if I added 
`window.` before actually solved the issue:
`window.localStorage.removeItem('myItem');`